# Read from Kafka in Spark - Different Behaviour in interactive mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have setup a single node Kafka (version 3.5.0 with zookeeper) on google compute engine VM. Trying to read the json data from a simple spark structured streaming code running on google dataproc cluster. Streaming job just parses the data and writes to console (or target storage).

```
# note: schema has all input fields with right datatype. To test, also tried marking all fields as StringType()

result_df = kafka_stream_df\
        .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),schema).alias("parsed_value"), col("timestamp").alias("kafka_timestamp"))\
        .selectExpr("parsed_value.*","kafka_timestamp")\
        .withColumn("event_date",col("timestamp").cast('date'))
```

Created a Kafka topic with single partition. Data published to Kafka is in json format. To test, I'm passing 1 record at a time in both the below approach.

**case-1:** when I publish the data to Kafka topic from a file using below command, I can read the complete data from spark streaming code, irrespective of data volume. Tried publishing data over 5KB, worked well, can read all data and generated results.

```
# passed the same record from case-2, copied to file test_data.json using vim

./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testtopic < /home/user_name/test_data.json
```

**case-2:** when I publish the data to Kafka topic interactively from shell on VM, I can read all fields only if record size is <4KB. If record published to Kafka is exceeding 4KB, then spark generates null/blank values in the output for all fields.

```
# passed same record used in case-1 interactively on VM
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testtopic
```

**Summary**: Spark generates correct result if the data is published to Kafka from a file irrespective of record size. If the data is published to kafka interactively (ie. not from file input), spark generates correct data only if record size is <4KB. If record size exceeds 4KB, spark generates blank/null value for all fields.

**Question**: what could be the reason for this behaviour, when we pass record >4KB interactively to kafka, spark generates null record, whereas spark can generates correct data when same record of >4KB is published to Kafka from a file?

Comment: File size should not matter. Can you share your JSON file? Or show `kafka-console-consumer`? Using shell redirection will interpret line breaks as unique records, which will cause Kafka values like just `{` for multi-line JSON objects, therefore will fail to be parsed. Otherwise, if you manually enter in some invalid JSON strings, that'll also fail. Keep in mind that there is an input buffer being build in the CLI code, so 4KB could be the max... Spark can also write JSON files to Kafka, so why not use that?

Comment: added the json record at the end of question above. Tried consuming from kafka-console-consumer, it is displaying data only upto 4KB, so guessing there could be some limit of 4KB on CLI. I was doing a POC on spark reading from Kafka, so was testing by publishing data from CLI.

Comment: The limit could actually be your terminal itself / the clipboard buffer. I assume you're not typing that whole string out manually. The producer itself will accept records up to 1MB in size, by default

Comment: got it. I'm not typing, just copy,paste on terminal from file.